# PyThreadState_Get: no current thread error when calculating roc curve with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate multiple (~3000) roc curves using sklearn.metrics in a loop and add results to list.

Basically code looks something like this:

```
from sklearn import metrics

results = []

for y_test in dataset:

    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, y_test, pos_label=1)

    results.append([fpr, tpr, thresholds])
```

It works ok, however after ~2k iterations I get PyThreadState_Get: no current thread that points to sklearn files:

```
    Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Current thread 0x000017a4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 356 in _binary_clf_curve
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 534 in roc_curve
```

I suspect that it's a memory issue, however I was not able to solve it by simply freeing up more RAM, Windows resource monitor does not show that all ram is used during error either.
Maybe someone has encountered such issue before?

I'm using Python 3 on Windows 7 (64bit)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i remember this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task.

Comment: its difficult to identify without data which you are working with, but one this is pretty sure something is going wrong with your y_score, which is causing error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and the problem was because of the data points I passed to the roc_curve function. Something must be weird about the data. So try to fix data points issue should solve this problem.